# Fine uploader S3 metadata size exceed

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I am using fineuploader-5.0.7 s3 to upload the files directly to S3.
And I also setup endpoint to my php backend file.

```
var options = {
    debug: true,
    template: "qq-template-manual-noedit",
    autoUpload: false,
    multiple: false,
    request: {
        endpoint: UploadVars.endpoint,
        accessKey: UploadVars.accessKey,

    },
    signature: {
        endpoint:   "entry_essay_handler_s3.php"
    },
    uploadSuccess: {
        endpoint:   "entry_essay_handler_s3.php?success"
    },
    // required if non-File-API browsers, such as IE9 and older, are used
    iframeSupport: {
        localBlankPagePath: 'blank.html'
    },
    validation: {
        allowedExtensions: UploadVars.allowedExtensions,
        sizeLimit: UploadVars.sizeLimit
    },
    showMessage: function(message) {
        // Using Twitter Bootstrap's classes and jQuery selector and method
        console.log(message);
        $('#imageUploadmsg').html(message);
        $('#imageUploadmsg').css('visibility','visible');
    },
    objectProperties: {
        key: function (id) {
            return getUploadPath(id);
        }
    },
    chunking: {
        enabled: true
    },
    retry: {
        enableAuto: true
    },
    resume: {
        enabled: true
    },
    messages:{
        unsupportedBrowser: "You need to update your browser in order to upload a file."
    }
};
```

This entry_essay_handler_s3.php will parse the custom form element and stores them on to database.
The thing is some of the field contains more than 2kb text and it is submitted to aws along with file attachment.
And I got this error from aws.
Your metadata headers exceed the maximum allowed metadata size
I don't want to submit meta data to aws, but i should get the meta data in my php endpoint.

I use these code in my php

```
switch ($k):
    case 'key':
        $key = $val;
        break;
    case 'bucket':
        $bucket = $val;
        break;
    case 'x-amz-meta-title':
        $_POST['title'] = urldecode($val);
        break;
    case 'x-amz-meta-caption':
        $_POST['caption'] = urldecode($val);
        break;
    case 'x-amz-meta-essay':
        $_POST['essay'] = urldecode($val);
        break;
    case 'x-amz-meta-entry_custom1':
        $_POST['entry_custom1'] = urldecode($val);
        break;
    case 'x-amz-meta-entry_custom2':
        $_POST['entry_custom2'] = urldecode($val);
        break;
    case 'x-amz-meta-entry_custom3':
        $_POST['entry_custom3'] = urldecode($val);
        break;
    case 'x-amz-meta-entry_custom4':
        $_POST['entry_custom4'] = urldecode($val);
        break;
    case 'x-amz-meta-entry_custom5':
        $_POST['entry_custom5'] = urldecode($val);
        break;
endswitch;
```

Answer (score 0):

All parameters associated with the file will be sent to the upload endpoint, in this case, S3.  It's not clear from your question where these parameters are coming from.  If you only want to send parameters to your uploadSuccess endpoint, in this case, use the [setUploadSuccessParams API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods-s3.html#setUploadSuccessParams).